# How to reclassify in Rastercalc?

Tags: qgis, reclassify, raster-calculator

I now need to reclassify, I'm using rastercalc... but I can't get the syntax right!!

I need that values >0 become 1

I found this example...
eq( [relief]@1, [mask]@4, 150 )

so I tried:
( [raster A insularis_1]@1, > 0, 1) and I absolutely failed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply need to use following expression

raster A insularis_1@1 > 0

The expression means ,  set all values greater than 0 as 1 and others as 0.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I didn't know I could do that !