# Multiband Raster Reclassification in QGIS

Tags: qgis, reclassify

I have a raster which nodata is 0,0,0 in all three bands, how can I reclassify them into 255,255,255?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the 'Raster Calculator' under the Raster dropdown menu? (see e.g. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27988/how-to-reclassify-in-rastercalc). You can also use GRASS under Processing -> Toolbox (see e.g. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121532/how-to-reclass-a-raster-with-reclassify-grid-values-in-qgis).

Comment: Also, take a look at this:
http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2016/09/05/serval/

Answer (score 1):

QGIS Raster Calculator returns only one image at a time, so you need to calculate it for each band.

```
# Band1
    (BM24_10K_0501@1 = 0) * (BM24_10K_0501@2 = 0) * (BM24_10K_0501@3 = 0) * 255
    + (((BM24_10K_0501@1 > 0) + (BM24_10K_0501@2 > 0) + (BM24_10K_0501@3 > 0))>0) * BM24_10K_0501@1
```

This may look complicated;

- When the cell is RGB(0,0,0), the first line becomes `(0=0)*(0=0)*(0=0)*255`, which means `True*True*True*255` or `1*1*1*255`. So it outputs cell value `255`.
- At the same time the second line becomes `((0>0)+(0>0)+(0>0))>0*band1`, which means `((False+False+False)>0)*band1` or `(0+0+0)>0*band1`. So it returns zero.
- Overall, this expression replaces Band1= `0` by `255` if input cells are RGB(0,0,0).

Repeat this for Band 2 and Band 3:

```
# Band2
    (BM24_10K_0501@1 = 0) * (BM24_10K_0501@2 = 0) * (BM24_10K_0501@3 = 0) * 255
    + (((BM24_10K_0501@1 > 0) + (BM24_10K_0501@2 > 0) + (BM24_10K_0501@3 > 0))>0) * BM24_10K_0501@2
# Band3
    (BM24_10K_0501@1 = 0) * (BM24_10K_0501@2 = 0) * (BM24_10K_0501@3 = 0) * 255
    + (((BM24_10K_0501@1 > 0) + (BM24_10K_0501@2 > 0) + (BM24_10K_0501@3 > 0))>0) * BM24_10K_0501@3
```

Final step: Merge these new rasters into single raster.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to work with raster calculator you can do this task by using `Reclassify values (simple)` from `SAGA processing toolbox`.

[image]

Choose Grid value equals low value as condition and create a lookup table with lowest and highest value 0 to be replaced by 255. This will not touch your other values (means no need to enter the whole table from 0 to 254).

Do this for all 3 bands, e.g. by using batch processing.

PS: just tried with `reclassify by table` (non SAGA) with no success, no idea why. However, the SAGA tool works just fine.